# Is product of random numbers still random?

Tags: random

If I have a function f that generates a random number uniformly distributed between 1 and 5 then can I say that g=f*f generates a random number uniformly distributed between 1 and 25?

Comment: Definitely not. g can only equal 1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,15,16,20,25, and some of these values are more likely than others

Comment: I guess it's a random real number.

Comment: Depends if it the distribution is continuous or discrete

Comment: Also in continuos case the product is not a uniform distribution

Comment: Why not? All values from 1 to 25 are equally probable in the continuous case

Comment: Take randomly two sides of a rectangle from [1,5]. Is it equally probable having area A=1 or A=10?

Comment: @Blex got it, thanks

Comment: Just like to point out that "random"≠"uniformly distributed".

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern A good point.  I have seen arguments in which it is assumed that any statement which might be true or false is 50/50 so if there are 20 statements then it is less than one in a million that they are all true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Discrete case**

Fairly obvious not as there some numbers between $1$ and $25$ that you will never get: $7, 11, 13, 14, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24$.

The sum is a bit better behaved, all of $2$ to $10$ will be possible but still not uniform.  Consider the similar problem of two dice: $7$ is much more likely than $2$ or $12$.

**Continuous case**

Also not uniform.

For the sum, the PDF will rise from $0$ at $0$ linearly to a maximum at the mid-point and then fall linearly back to $0$ at $10$.

For the product, also not uniform.  I was calculating it but it seems redundant now.